# Can I force Calibre flow mode to ignore page breaks and never skip pages like paginated mode?

Tags: epub, calibre, ebook-readers

The icon for **Flow mode** shows a viewport with the bottom half of one page on the top followed by the top half of the next page underneath it.

But I've found that when I activate **Flow mode** this only happens for regular pages. Certain boundaries such as ends of chapters do not scroll, even with Flow mode on, they jump.

You scroll to the bottom of the chapter, and then instead of having those lines go up the viewport, and seeing the lines of the next chapter appear on the bottom, it skips the whole page.

Is there a way to get Calibre to do this?

Comment: Since Community bumped this question... Are you talking about breaks at the end of each .xhtml file? Because scrolling between different files is probably not going to be implemented. The workaround, of course, is to put the content you want to be able scroll through into one file.

Comment: It was unclearly worded, sorry. I meant even in "Flow mode" you cannot scroll a book without jumps, beginning to end. The bottom of the last page of one chapter won't continue scrolling, revealing the first page of the next chapter. Instead scrolling jumps from the full last page of Chapter 1 to a full first page of Chapter 2. If you look at the icon for the Flow Mode button, it's exactly what I mean, and thus the functionality is a lie in these cases.

Comment: As I said, I suspect that each chapter is in a separate xhtml file within the epub.

Comment: @beaker Ah, gotcha. The "files" thing threw me off. I get it now, .epubs zip up a bunch of .xhtml files, which are the sections of the book. But it's strange that it wouldn't be implemented. Rendering files in order into a continuous ebook is implemented, and "Flow mode" is also implemented, but has this glaring oversight that deceives expectations.

Comment: You can use Calibre to edit the ePub structure and merge the individual files.

Answer (score 1):

Calibre doesn't support this natively, but you can get a similar effect by adding space to the top and bottom of each chapter.

In Calibre's ebook viewer, go to preferences and then styles, and enter

```
body.calibre-viewer-scrolling::before, body.calibre-viewer-scrolling::after
{ display: block; height: 100%; content: ""; }
```

as a custom stylesheet. Chapter boundaries will then appear as a page of blank space, which the viewer can scroll across seamlessly.

Note this also adds a blank page to the start of each book, so you'll have to scroll down when you first open a book to see the text.

Answer (score 0):

Well I use linux and I'm not sure if that's what you're after but there is a yellow icon representing a scroll at the top right of the viewer's window next to the find next - find prev vertical arrows. When you mouse over it says "Switch to scroll mode… etc." You click this and it should switch to scroll mode.

Comment: That button says "Switch to flow mode" for me, that's what I'm referring to in the title of the question. But this flow mode is unusable. It doesn't change screens like turning pages (paged mode) but it also doesn't scroll like a web page. It's turning out to be a costly usability issue, in terms of time wasted on bad UI while trying to look stuff up and read.